# Server problems

Tags: c++, sockets, server

I try to make multithreaded server (C++, Visual Studio 2017), but have a problem: every time I start launch my .exe I get connected to port 52428 (while I even not start client). Why is heppening and how should I get rid of it.

Server:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if(err != 0)
        return -1;

    sockaddr_in local;
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(8080);
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    SOCKET s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local));
    cout << "Start server..." << endl;
    int r = listen(s, 10000);
    while(true)
    {
        sockaddr_in remote;
        int j = sizeof(remote);
        SOCKET newS = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*) &remote, &j);
        if (newS == INVALID_SOCKET)
            continue;
        Socket sock = {newS, remote.sin_port, const_cast<const char*>(inet_ntoa(remote.sin_addr))}; // save socket, port and IP
        cout << " Connect to port " << sock.port << endl;
        thread thr(processing, ref(sock));
        thr.join();
    }
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview might show you where the connection is coming from

Comment: You should zero-initialize `local` otherwise all the other fields are garbage